# Dynamically change Commerce Customer profile type on checkout

Tags: commerce

I need the following in Drupal Commerce:

- On checkout, two radios should be presented (e.g. Email & Postal)
- Upon selection of one of these, a different customer profile type should be attached to the order
- Only fields related to the selected profile type should dynamically show up.

I'm perfectly able to accomplish this through FormAPI, but that wouldn't be tied to the Commerce system unfortunately.

Someone knows how the right way?

Thanks

Comment: In light of Ryan's answer, here's a follow-up question:
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/97609/adding-validation-handler-before-drupal-checks-if-field-is-required

Answer (score 1):

If you can accomplish this through the Forms API, then go for it. There's no specific Commerce way to make this happen.