# Alter $form before _form_validate() is called?

Tags: forms

I need to conditionally set the `#required` property of a specific form field to FALSE. I know already that the requirement check is performed in `_form_validate()`. However this function is executed BEFORE any other custom attached validation handlers as it is in fact responsible for calling them.

So I'd like to know if there's a way to alter `$form` of `$form_state` BEFORE `_form_validate()` is called...?

Or maybe there are ways to perform the requirement check at a later time in validation?

Thanks

PS: One could also do reverse thinking (make the field optional and require it in a custom validation handler), but there are reasons I cannot do this.

Comment: you can use hook_form_alter() to alter required property of field based on conditions.

Comment: The property needs to be changed on submit but before validation. `hook_form_alter()` alters the form array at build time.

Comment: whats the issue you are facing when you change the requrired property at build time?